# Drawing a shaded region but with functions y-dependent

Tags: tikz-pgf

He, I am trying to draw the following imagine on Latex using tikz and pgfplots
[image]

With the following code

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = middle,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            xmin=-1, xmax=2.5, ymin=0, ymax=2.5,
            xmajorticks=false,
            ymajorticks=false,
            legend style={at={(0,1)},anchor=north east}
        ]
        \addplot[smooth, thick, samples=200, red, name path=curve1] ({x},{x^2/2});
        \addlegendentry{$\frac{x^{2}}{2}$}
        \addplot[smooth, thick, samples=200, name path=curve2] ({x},{x^2});
        \addlegendentry{$x^{2}$}
        \addplot[smooth, thick, samples=200, blue, name path=curve3] ({x^2},{x});
        \addlegendentry{$y^2$}
        \addplot[smooth, thick, samples=200, teal, name path=curve4] ({x^2/2},{x});
        \addlegendentry{$\frac{y^{2}}{2}$}
    
        \addplot[fill=magenta,fill opacity=0.4] fill between[of=curve2 and curve3,
            soft clip={domain=1:1.2599}];
        \addplot[fill=magenta,fill opacity=0.4] fill between[of=curve3 and curve4,
            soft clip={domain=1.2599:1.5874}];
        \addplot[fill=magenta,fill opacity=0.4] fill between[of=curve1 and curve4,
            soft clip={domain=1.5874:2}];
        \addlegendentry{$D$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I obtain this result

[image]

Which clearly is not what i want. I think the problem is that i am trying to shade the region between a x-dependent function and a y-dependent function, but i have no idea how to fix this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would construct the area segment by segment. While `split` would allow us

```
\addplot[path only] fill between[
  of=blackblue and redteal,
  split,
  every segment no 1/.style={fill=magenta!40}];
```

to only fill the middle area, the legend entry has no color then.

The easiest approach for me was to `\addplot[fill=magenta!40]` and use `no segments={0, 2}` to disable the filling for the other areas:

```
\addplot[fill=magenta!40] fill between[
  of=blackblue and redteal,
  split,
  no segments={0, 2}];
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\tikzset{
  fill between/no segments/.style={% better for legendentry
    /utils/temp/.style={every segment no ##1/.style=path only},
    /utils/temp/.list={#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xmin=-1, xmax=2.5, ymin=0, ymax=2.5,
    xmajorticks=false,
    ymajorticks=false,
    legend style={at={(0,1)},anchor=north east},
    thick, samples=200, smooth,
]
\addplot[red,  name path=red  ] ({x},{x^2/2});
\addlegendentry{$\frac{x^{2}}{2}$}
\addplot[      name path=black] ({x},{x^2});
\addlegendentry{$x^{2}$}
\addplot[blue, name path=blue ] ({x^2},{x});
\addlegendentry{$y^2$}
\addplot[teal, name path=teal ] ({x^2/2},{x});
\addlegendentry{$\frac{y^{2}}{2}$}

\path[name path=blackblue, intersection segments={of=black and blue, sequence={L3[reverse] -- R3}}];
\path[name path=redteal,   intersection segments={of=red   and teal, sequence={L2 -- R2[reverse]}}];
\addplot[fill=magenta!40] fill between[of=blackblue and redteal, split, no segments={0, 2}];
\addlegendentry{$D$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xmin=-1, xmax=3.5, ymin=0, ymax=10.5,
    domain=0:3.5,
    xmajorticks=false,
    ymajorticks=false,
    legend style={at={(0,1)},anchor=north east},
    thick, samples=125, smooth,
]
\addplot[red,  name path=red  ] ({x},{2*x});
\addlegendentry{$y=2x$}
\addplot[      name path=black] ({x},{x});
\addlegendentry{$y=x$}
\addplot[blue, name path=blue, domain=.1:3.5] ({x},{2*pi/x});
\addlegendentry{$y=2\pi/x$}
\addplot[teal, name path=teal, domain=.1:3.5] ({x},{3*pi/x});
\addlegendentry{$y=3\pi/x$}

\path[name path=blackblue, intersection segments={of=black and blue, sequence={R1 -- L2}}];
\path[name path=redteal,   intersection segments={of=red   and teal, sequence={L1 -- R2}}];
\addplot[fill=magenta!40] fill between[of=blackblue and redteal, split, no segments={0, 2}];
\addlegendentry{$D$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, do you mind explain to me what the code after "intersection segments" does? So i can apply this method with other functions, in particular i want to apply this method so i can fill the area between the following curves: y=2x, y=x, y=2pi/x, y=3pi/x. Copy and pastying your code in this case, does not work.

Comment: Take a look at the manual about the [`sequence` key](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/libs-fillbetween#sec-46.6). The `intersection segments` basically splits both paths at their intersection and counts all segments. The second segment of the first path (the **l**eft one in the `of` key) is `L2`. The third one in the **r**ight path of `of` is `R3`. They can be reversed via `[reverse]`. Of course, you could just find the *x* value for the intersection yourself and just replot the area which needs you to do math.

Comment: You can always add something like `[draw=green, ->]` to these `\path`s to essentially debug what the `intersection segments` thing does.